# How to host a .com or a .net website in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Windows Azure, and from what I have read online it appears that any website hosted in Windows Azure needs to be a ***.azurewebsites.net*** website.  So, if I had a website *www.mysite.com* hosted elsewhere, then it seems I cannot host this same site in Windows Azure, since I would have to use *mysite.azurewebsites.net* as the website url.

**Question**: Is above fact true? I could not find any documentation or any online article on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly host your own domain using Azure, as detailed in [this support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2990804) (which links to a walk-through).

You can bind your domain to a website or cloud service, just I *believe* this is only something available in a paid tier. (Follow-up: Using a domain is only available in [Shared, Basic or Standard mode](https://support2.microsoft.com/common/survey.aspx?scid=sw;en;3864&showpage=1).)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. You can have other domains, but in the background it will always has a .azurewebsites.net. See my blog as an example: http://www.buzzfrog.se. (This is only an example of the hosting.)

Here is an article how to do it: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

/dag

Comment: I cannot access any online article that explains how to use custom domain. May be there is another url?

Comment: Here is an artikle: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/